# Mac OS X detailed system administration reference material

Tags: macos

I've been searching for a while, and I'm struggling to find any decent reference material that explains how Mac OS 10.8 is configured with reference to things like `init.d`/`launchd`, where default installation directories, are etc.

I understand a fair bit about Unix, I just want to understand the OSX implementation.

Can anyone point me to a good reference for this?

The reason I ask is that I have both MAMP and MAMP PRO installed and I'd like to remove MAMP PRO. But I don't want to do it "blindly"; I want to understand where things so I know what to remove.

Answer (score 1):

Apple provides many man pages, which is how I come to understand some of the details to their tools. You can access them from the command line like Unix man pages (e.g. `man launchctl`), or you can read them on [Apple's man page index](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/).

Apple provides this documentation on their [Mac Developer page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac). This page includes a lot of programming information, so you might be better off starting with the man pages.

Answer (score 0):

All the documentation you could ever want about OS X is in the [Mac Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/)

It's quite extensive.  I believe the document you're looking for is the [Daemons and Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i).  Also, the [Daemons and Agents Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794) might help.  Those documents contain the information about `launchd` and related daemons.